# tomcat7 tuning on linux : how to know what should be changed?

Tags: linux, performance, tomcat7

I have big enterprise JAVA application , running on several machines under tomcat7.

There are different performance problems such slow response , server hangs etc.

I want to try to play with different params like maxThread , maxConnection ,acceptCount and so on .

But before change them, how can I check that I run out of connections for example and I need to increase it ? Or everything else , like acceptCount that should be increased ?

Comment: You should consider asking the same question in http://serverfault.com/ as this is clearly a server-related question and not programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, Apache Tomcat performance issues are with the underlying JavaVM configuration, in my experience those are mainly with the size of the permGen, and other memory settings. I have been able to troubleshoot quite a few of them using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), which visualizes a lot of the JVM memory ops. Would also highly recommend [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/).

IMHO *maxThread* and other Tomcat-specific parameters have rarely been the source of application performance issues, but it's the JVM settings where most issues are.

Start with minimum of these settings:
-Xms1024M -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to find the problem before starting "fixing" things.

There are several applications to monitor your servers and check where the problems are. You can try appdynamics, newrelic, ruxit, or any other application monitoring product. (Some have free version offers that comes handy)

Then you search for your bottlenecks, they can be anywhere, server, database, network, jvm, ... depending on your application and your architecture.

And once you find the problem, you can start fixing it.

Good luck!